# NCalc mathematical expression in C# -

Tags: c#, ncalc

I'm using NCalc to create Mathematical expression in C#:

```
       Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");

        Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

But second line gives me an error - "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type int and object"

How to solve this problem?

Comment: cast?..................

Comment: You need to cast the result as the value will need unboxing! e.g. `(int)e.Evaluate`, this is assuming that `e.Evaluate` does in fact result in an `int` and not some representative type or container type

Comment: Isn't the error message explicit enough? The null exception one can be weird for beginners, but that one is really pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 2):

The `Evaluate()` method returns an `object` (from the [source code](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Evaluant.Calculator/Expression.cs)), so you need to insert a cast to make this work:

```
Debug.Assert(17 == (int) e.Evaluate());
```

The "simple expressions" example on the [NCalc home page](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is incorrect.

Comment: I tried casting but then I got an error - 'Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll'